Unknown specific generator on a non-invertible semigroup homomorphic signature valid?
There's a quantum polynomial time algorithm to solve DLPs in semigroups, without inverses, so apparently there's nothing to research with those semigroups.
I don't know if this is an area of research or there are some bibliography available. I've designed a (toy) signature scheme that uses a kind of homomorphic encryption. It's possible to be used with any semigroup or monoid that's not a  group, i. e., without inverses of the elements possible, but we can center in singular matrices in $Mat(n,q)$ for better understanding.
The key concept is to choose a generator of a non-group generated by a generator $G\in Mat(n,p)$, p prime, that's not invertible and of rank $n-1$. The generator ${is secret}$ and is one of many in the same group generated by $G$ itself. The order of $G$ is $o=p^{n-1}-1$.
We choose $c,k\in\mathbb{Z}_o$ and our secret information is $\left<c,k,G\right>$, and as a public information $\left<G^k,G^c\right>$.
To sign a number $h$, we use the following formula:
$(G^k G^q)^h=G^c$, the signature is $\left<G^q\right>$. Verification is straightforward, just check $G^q$ makes the equality true.
In order to get $q$ we apply the formula in the exponents we know ${secretly}$, so $q\equiv c/h-k$ $\left(\mod o\right)$. We publish $G^q$ and we're done.
The formula works even if computing $-k \mod o$ is fallacious as inverses does not exists, this can be explained, but we cannot apply the obvious formula to get $G^q$:
$G^q=G^{c/h}/{G^k}$
So the question is, there's an obvious attack on this signature scheme and also if there's some research and literature in this area?
Notes:
As a check and as a reference code here's a sage/python program at https://github.com/danielnager/soitm/blob/main/check.py
$G^c$ commute with $G^q$ so it's not necessary to put all the matrix $G^q$ as a signature, only a row.
